# What finance data sets would be particularly useful to release?

Tags: usa, finance

The U.S. government publishes a range of finance data sets (see, e.g., www.Treasury.gov/financedata). What additional data sets that the government already collects would be valuable if released in open, machine readable formats?

Edit: Disclaimer: I work at Treasury, which publishes www.treasury.gov/financedata and is involved in open data in the finance sector.

Comment: The first step to answering that question is for the government to answer another one: what datasets do you have that could be released?

Comment: That is helpful feedback. That is one of the reasons that the new Open Data Policy announced on May 9, 2013, will require U.S. federal agencies to list data sets that could be made public. See p. 8 of the Open Data Policy here: http://www.whitehouse.gov/sites/default/files/omb/memoranda/2013/m-13-13.pdf.

Comment: A very broad question. Ideally, all the data would be fine :) Now, the problem seems to be that sequestration etc. keeps squeezing the definition of "data sets that the government already collects". Would be nice to reverse the trend.

Answer (score 1):

World Bank Donor Data - how donor funding is being spent by project/country/donor/implementer etc.